# Jsf2 ajax render id not found

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, render

Why i get "  contains an unknown id ':commentTextArea' - cannot locate it in the context of the component commentLink" error?

majorra 2.1.7

How i can render commentTextArea.

```
<ui:repeat var="parentComment" value="#{commentTree.parentCommentsWrapper}"> ....
                          <h:form>

                            <h:commandLink id="commentLink" value="comment"
                                style="height:20px;width:20px;padding: 0; margin: 0;"
                                action="#{parentComment.changeEditable}">
                                **<f:ajax render=":commentTextArea"></f:ajax>**
                            </h:commandLink>

                            </h:form>        <h:panelGroup id="commentTextArea">
                                <br />
                                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{parentComment.editable}">
                                    <h:form >
                                    <h:inputTextarea rows="2" cols="20"
                                        value="#{commentTree.newCommentText}" 
                                        style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica;font-size:12px;width:365px;margin-right: 4px;margin-left: -1px;">
                                    </h:inputTextarea>
                                    <h:commandButton id="newCommentButton" value="+"
                                        style="height:20px;width:20px;padding: 0; margin: 0;"
                                        action="#{commentTree.saveChildComment(parentComment.comment)}" >
                                    </h:commandButton>
                                    </h:form>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

'

Answer (score 0):

The id `:commentTextArea` is an absolute id and relative to the view root. However, `ui:repeat` is a NamingContainer and "wraps" your `commentTextArea`. (Check the html source in browser to see what id is generated)

A simple solution would be to use only one form in your 'ui:repeat'. Then the relative id with

```
<f:ajax render="commentTextArea">
```

(without `:`) would work.

Comment: still same error,  <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'commentTextArea' - cannot locate it in the context of the component commentLink . The generated id for that commentTextArea is  <span id="j_idt106:0:commentTextArea"/>

Comment: what you meant by current version.

Comment: The version with only one form.

Comment: this is the only version i have. i cant put all stuffs into one form. if i did so only last command link in the loop submits the data into backing bean. other links not populate backing bean. please help me to  get it working. thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, maybe I was not clear enough. I thought about one form _inside_ the `ui:repeat`.